# Insecure '^' jshint issue

Tags: jslint, jshint

I am getting this jshint error "Insecure '^'" from this line of javascript:

```
var test = content.replace(/d=([^&]*)/, 'd=test');
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Check *Tolerate . and [^...]. in /RegExp/*.

> true if . and [^...] should be allowed in RegExp literals. They match
>   more material than might be expected, allowing attackers to confuse
>   applications. These forms should not be used when validating in secure
>   applications.

[Source](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html).

Comment: Thanks for this but what modification do I need to make to my javascript to fix the error?

Comment: @amateur I wouldn't really worry about it myself. Crockford thinks it's too liberal, but that's only one man's opinion. You could swap it with something like `\w` or `\d` depending on what you expect there.